# get gmail email contents and transfer to google spreadsheet and arrange accordingly

Tags: email, google-apps-script

Hi I'm just wondering if i could extract all email contents of a certain emails on a label and put them into a google spreadsheet.Its very tiring to open every email and copy and paste every data to a spreadsheet to arrange accordingly. ive tried to create a macro in vb to arrange the emails but still i would need to open each email just to get the data and put them on my excel file.

here is the sample email content i want to arrange based on their labels and each email will be displayed per row and column:

CO type:IV ONLY

TYPE AUTO:Manual
DATE:11/21/2016 1:49:11 PM 
CAR Type: MITSUBISHI
Company address: PEAK 
Price: 8,000.00

CA: Michael,John
SPO: SINGLE
ADD: UNIT 3 San Franciscvo, Canada
LM : Oyster
SOI: Factory Worker
POS: 1st mate
ADD: UNIT 3 San Diego, California

And what i want is to arrange them based on the headers ive created:which is before beggining of every mail until the colon(:) mark. I've already done it by searching the begining of word until the colon and by using cut and paste on excel but still takes alot of time due to manual opening and pasting of emails on my file. is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Save Gmail add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-and-attachmen/nflmnfjphdbeagnilbihcodcophecebc) for saving the email metadata to a Google Sheet. It also saves the messages to Drive. (disclaimer: I am the author of the add-on)

It can be done with Google Script attached to the Google Sheet, something like this snippet.

```
function getGmailData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread in:inbox", 0, 20);
  for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
    sheet.appendRow([threads[t].getDate(), threads[t].getId(), threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject()])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what im looking for is for the data to be arrange on the spreadsheet because i would stil need to edit some info of those

Comment: oh is see but it seems like i'm having a problem with the getdate() .

Comment: Google script worked great, thank you! Had to change threads[t].getDate() to threads[t].getLastMessageDate(). To dig into message details use GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[t]) and check out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message

Answer (score 3):

I coded what you want on Google App Script and I have made a YouTube video that explains this in details. You may watch it from the link below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdgCVqtcIw4

However if you would like to extract specific texts from the body of the email, you would need to use regular expressions. Part 2 of my video series explains how to achieve this. You may watch it here:

https://youtu.be/nI1OH3pAz6s?t=9

You may also read the full step-by-step explanation from my blog:
[https://codewondo.com/2021/07/29/gmail-emails-to-spreadsheet/](https://www.codewondo.com/2021/07/29/gmail-emails-to-spreadsheet/)

You can also get the full code from GitHub from the following link:

- [GitHub: Get Gmail Emails into Google Sheet](https://gist.github.com/MoayadAbuRmilah/fcb75d0bf5be50b83e36e05746e2722d)
- [GitHub: Extract Body Contents from Gmail Emails](https://gist.github.com/MoayadAbuRmilah/5835369fdebbecf980029f7339e4d769)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it. In fact, I have a Google script that does just that. My script has a web UI, where you set a before and after date fields and a field for the file name. Once you start the script it gets all emails (not **threads**, Gmail Service works with threads, if you want to search for individual messages, you need to use Gmail API) and then you can output anything about it to a Google Spreadsheet.

Instead of using VB I would recommend to use GAS. You can use `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel")` to get the label you want to extract the messages from and then use `.getThreads()` to grab all the threads (the conversations) from the label.

Read on what you can do with threads [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) and what you can do with messages [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message). Personally I used Gmail API and used

```
queriedMessages =
      Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userInfo.mail, {
        'q': queryString,
        'pageToken': execProperties.nextPageId
      });
```

and then I can extract the info I want from individual messages. The query string is basically what you would put into Gmail to search for the email, so you can use something like `label:"This-label"`

Comment: do you have any video tutorial for that? so i could easily get the idea of gmail script . because im unfamiliar with gmail scripting right now. and i need to get the process the fastest possible time so  i wont need to do manual copy and pasting of emails. Thank alot

Comment: @kkk it's basic JavaScript with added functions. If you know JavaScript you practically know the basics of GAS. There are only limitations and extra features to consider after that. Your best friend is Google's own documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app). This is not Gmail Script, it's Google script, meaning that it covers everything, from Gmail, to docs, spreadsheets, calendars etc. If it's on G-Suite (as it's now called) you can probably script it. It's easy to navigate, so start with what you want to work with and look for objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late response, but hopefully my answer might help others. My add-on was just released, it does exactly the mentioned function:

- iterate through yesterdays emails
- parse data from them
- add new rows to spreadsheet daily with the parsed data

Here is the add-on link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-parser-analytics/ilaecpapiiijoeijcffhnlhfjimammek

This add-on is advanced version of that kind of scripting:

```
//Variables of your choice here

  var sheet = '';
  var query = '';
  var array2d = getEmailsInbox(array2d, query);    

//Proccess all emails that match query and add them into  2-dimensional array

  function getEmailsInbox(array2d, query){
  var emails = [];
  var thds = GmailApp.search(query);
  for(var i in thds){
    var msgs = thds[i].getMessages();
            for(var j in msgs){
    var dt = msgs[j].getDate();
    var mail = msgs[j].getReplyTo();
    var subj = msgs[j].getSubject();
    var body = msgs[j].getPlainBody();

      emails.push([dt, mail, subj, body]);

    }
    }
    return emails;
  }


//Function to add objects from 2 dimensional array to a spreadsheet as rows

    function appendInboxEmails(sheet, array2d){
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
    }


//Put that function on trigger or run once

    function run() {
    if(typeof array2d !== 'undefined' && array2d.length > 0) {
             appendInboxEmails(sheet, array2d);
             array2d = [];
    }
    }
```